# alert message is not showing after inserting data in database using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, alert

[image]

I have a code in which I inserted data in database and I am using ajax.
This is my code:

```
$('.submit_request').click(function (event) {

var frm = $('#formin');

var postForm = frm.serialize();
   $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST', 
                    url: 'addingJournal.php', 
                    data: postForm, 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data.success){

                      alert('Journal Id added!!!');  
                  }
                    }
                });

});
```

Now after running, I got {"success":true} this message instead of alert.

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of code - paste it as text so people can easily copy and fix/improve it. I know you have pasted it in as plain text also, which makes the top image useless.

Comment: thanks for correcting it. I am new to stackoverflow, that's why this happened. Any suggestion for my query???

Comment: No, I've never touched AJAX. I only wanted to help you understand the formatting of a good question. Good questions are more likely to attract attention and therefore good answers. I suggest you read the https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in AJAX, but at a quick glance I'd say the problem is your if statement. Entering into the success block already means the operation was a success, so unless your data object also contains a success property, the if block will never be entered into.

Try this instead:

```
success: function (data) {
        alert('Journal Id added!!!');
}
```

Or this, if your expecting a value for data.success:

```
success: function (data) {
        alert(data.success);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure its succeeding? You can try adding some code to handle failure `error: function () { alert('failed!'); }`